# characteristic operation and expressing it as a summation

Tags: algorithm

Ok this is kind of really dumb but I am having trouble with doing summations (I know its embarassing). I am supposed to make an algorithm that gets subsets of three elements of a
set of n elements. I already done this and I have identified my character operation as well. What I am having trouble is with doing the summation. I have this

```
n-2  n-1     n
Σ    (Σ    ( Σ    j ))
i=1  j=i+1   k=j+1
```

Comment: This question is very vague and subjective in its current form. Its hard to tell what you are actually asking.

Comment: I am just asking how to do this summation that is all

Comment: I don't get it either. Are you asking how to code what you have written? Cause what you have written is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I am not asking how to code it. I just wanted to know how to calculate the summation, there was an answer here by someone and his solution was correct. I do not know why or how it got removed. This is a summation you get from a nested loop, anyways I figured this out so thanks everyone for atleast looking at it